# Generar una matriz con funciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me piden genere una matriz (de MxN) y la cargue con datos de la empresa (código, cliente y sueldo).
Y otra función que me permita recorrer mi matriz y ver si existe un cliente ingresando el codigo
**Pude hacer la función de mi matriz pero no tengo idea de como hacer que mi otra función recorra la matriz**

**Mi Funcion para la matriz**

```
##Carga de la matriz con los datos de la empresa
def carga_matriz (filas, columnas, vector):
    for i in range (filas):
        vector.append([0]*columnas)
        for j in range (columnas):
            vector[i][j]=input("Ingrese los elementos: ")
    print(vector, filas, columnas)
    #return f, c

f = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de filas: "))
c = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas: "))
v = []
carga_matriz(f, c, v)
```

Espero sus sugerencias, Saludos

Comment: El uso de nombres significativos para las variables ayuda inmensamente a su comprensión y depuración. Variables como `f, c, v` no dicen nada sobre su contenido, uso o significado. Para ayudarte tendría que entrar a adivinar que son, que hacen y para que sirven. Mucho trabajo. Lástima.

Answer (score 0):

No está muy claro qué quieres decir con lo de "ver si existe un cliente ingresando el codigo", pues por ningún sitio se menciona qué es lo que significan los números almacenados en la matriz.

Supongamos que esos números son los códigos de cliente que luego quieres buscar (es la suposición más razonable, pues de otro modo la pregunta no tiene sentido).

En esencia, lo que quieres es hacer una función que reciba un número y te devuelva `True` o `False` según ese número se encuentre o no se encuentre en la matriz.

### Recorrer matrices

Una matriz no es más que una lista cuyos elementos son otras listas. Así que para recorrer una matriz elemento a elemento lo que necesitas son dos bucles anidados. El bucle exterior irá obteniendo una fila de cada vez (que será a su vez una lista) y el bucle interior irá obteniendo cada elemento de esa lista. Por tanto necesitas saber cómo recorrer listas.

### Recorrer listas

Hay dos posibles métodos para esto, según necesites o no necesites los índices de cada elemento.

#### Usando los índices

Por ejemplo, para imprimir todos los elementos de una lista:

```
for indice in range(len(lista)):
   print(lista[indice])
```

#### Sin usar los índices

Si te fijas en el ejemplo anterior el índice sólo lo hemos usado para poder acceder al elemento. Lo que realmente nos importaba era el elemento y no el índice ya que éste no lo usamos para nada más. Este es un patrón muy habitual en python y para este caso puedes iterar directamente por la lista, en lugar de hacerlo por `range()`. Así:

```
for elemento in lista:
   print(elemento)
```

## Solución

Con esto ya tienes los ingredientes para la solución:

```
def codigo_en_matriz(codigo, matriz):
  for fila in matriz:
     for elemento in fila:
         if elemento == codigo:
             return True
  # Si hemos agotado los bucles sin haber retornado True
  # es que no estaba
  return False
```

### Mejora

Puedes ahorrarte el bucle interno, pues Python tiene el operador `in` que te permite saber si un cierto valor está o no en una lista: `valor in lista` te dirá `True` o `False`. En nuestro caso la lista sería cada fila:

```
def codigo_en_matriz(codigo, matriz):
  for fila in matriz:
     if codigo in fila:
        return True
  # Si hemos agotado el bucle sin haber retornado True
  # es que no estaba
  return False
```